# Firebase: verification email sent to Yahoo but not to Gmail

Tags: angular, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication, email-verification

Iam using firebase for the authentication part, I noticed that the registration to the website is different according to the provider (Yahoo or Gmail) and also according to the network. Verification email is only sent when using Yahoo, not Gmail. Also, once I noticed that when I was connected with the wifi of my smartphone I did not receive the verification email, but when I switched to the wifi of the house I managed to receive it. But sometimes it crashes with multiple WiFi networks.
I note that I also check spam. And i am using the correct code preconized by firebase authentication.
I would like to know if it depends on the network, it may be that the IP address is blocked and that is what causes the blocking of the mail? Or are there other factors?
THANKS.

Comment: The pipeline to send the verification emails is always the same. So if the email shows up for your Yahoo account, it stands to reason that the email is also being **sent** to your gmail account. 

Most likely the message is getting caught in your spam folder or in another spam filter somewhere along the way to your mail box.

Comment: that's what I didn't understand, I can't find the email sent in Gmail, I tested more than one email address, same result

Comment: I fixed the problem by filling in the page SMTP Settings. This may be a way to avoid blocking the receipt of verification emails.